# how to include quotes, &lt and &gt symbols inside asp:literal

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

Hope its almost clear from above subject line

I want to include a **lesser(and greater) than** symbol inside my asp:literal

To display something like

```
Select <Download>
```

I tried using this

```
<asp:Literal ID="LiteralDownload" runat="server" 
Text="Select &lt; Download &gt;"/>
```

But the ASP.NET page doesn't display the text

Any ideas/help ?

Vatsa

Comment: I think, you can assign this text to a label and put it inside literal..

Comment: @dotNETbeginner : Yes, even i can enter directly from the properties editor. But i need to set the Mode as **Rab Nawaz** has pointed out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the [`LiteraControl`'s Mode property to `PassThrough`.

The default is `Transform`: which  interpreted as html and does not show up

```
ltlMetaHolder.Mode = LiteralMode.PassThrough
```

OR as per commments from OP in this case

```
ltlMetaHolder.Mode = LiteralMode.Encode
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. But in my case the text appears when the **Mode** is set to **LiteralMode.Encode**

Comment: good, `LiteralMode.Encode` also does so, I thought, the above should work... anyway. I am happy ur problem is resolved